# Websockets Using Mulitple Channels Vs Single Channel

Tags: jquery, websocket, pusher

I have a website that is using pusher js to broadcast information about a series of randomly expiring events.  Is it more efficient to use one channel for all events, and broadcast an array of expiration times, or use one channel per event, and listen to all events on the page?

Also, is there any risk, in either case, of the page freezing due to trying to do to many JQuery actions (each event broadcast causes JQuery events to occur on the page).

Answer (score 0):

Channels in Pusher are very cheap. Having said that, if you batch the data (as an array) into a single event and broadcast that, then that may be more efficient than broadcasting multiple messages. The difference may be negligible though, so I would go for the approach that is simplest to implement; think about optimising it later if run into performance problems.

It's unlikely to cause noticeable freezes, although it depends on how many requests you are making.